# Bootstrap grid is ok on local, but broken on server

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Working on my first project with Bootstrap (and CSS in general).

In the following section, the columns look great on local for xs screen sizes, but on the server, the entire section is squashed over to the right. Can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

```
  <div class="container testimonials">
  <h2>What People Are Saying</h2>

  <div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-0">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-6">
  <div class="quotes">
    <blockquote>Extremely helpful! How to Interview is an easy read that hits all the major concerns about interviewing - and how to handle them appropriately. I recommend it to anyone who is trying to land a job.</blockquote>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-6">
  <div class="quotes">
    <blockquote>I interviewed at Google twice and didn't made the cut. I interviewed a third time -- trying the techniques in How to Interview -- and got the job. It changed the way I communicate and helped me get the job I wanted.</blockquote>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-0">
  </div>

  </div> <!-- /row -->
  </div> <!-- /testimonials -->
```

Comment: Is Bootstrap being loaded properly on your server? Can you post a link?

Comment: Not sure -- here's the link: http://howtointerviewguide.com/. Problematic section is "What people are saying" -- 3rd from bottom. Thank you!!

Comment: This is what I see: http://postimg.org/image/u5b3fvvol/ using Opera-developer 31, looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is excessive padding on the `testimonials` class:

```
.testimonials {
    /* ... */
    padding-left: 190px;
    padding-right: 190px;
}
```

It's not leaving enough room for the content.

Since those rules are coming from a separate CSS file `main.css` perhaps that file is different on your local server.

Comment: Agreed.  Andrea - instead of specifying padding to align your content, just do that same with Bootstrap columns, exactly the way you did it within the "row" div, but this time you would put a column on either side of the "row" div and one surrounding the "row" div.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes! That makes a lot of sense. Thanks! I'll try and report back.